# Get contact phone number by ID - empty Cursor

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-cursor

So I'm having trouble getting the phone number of a contact using its id.

This is the code I'm using to retrieve the number:

```
public String getNumber(){
        //gets numbers by id
        if (hasPhoneNumber){

            ContentResolver contentResolver=context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID+" = "+id,
                    null,
                    null
            ); //TODO : resolve empty cursor error
            //contact seems to have no data available?

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

                cursor.moveToNext();

                String contactId=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                Cursor phones=contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+" = "+contactId,
                        null,
                        null);

                if (phones.moveToFirst()){
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        this.number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    }
                }

                phones.close();
            } else {
                test("cursor error...");
            }

            cursor.close();

            return number;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It works with a few contacts but most show the "cursor error..." Toast (test("cursor error...") )

It's always the

> Cursor cursor

that has the error.

My guess is it's empty but I know I have those contacts phone numbers saved. How do I fix this? Are there other values I have to request?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

this is how I retrieve ID and Name:

```
contactCursor=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{
                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,//0 - Long
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY,//1 - String
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER,//2 - Integer
                },
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" ASC");
```

EDIT 2:

I have everything in a github repository: https://github.com/nicolas-d-torres/Syncc

The first block of Code is inside app/src/main/java/gtsarandum/syncc/SynccContact

the second in app/src/main/java/gtsarandum/syncc/ContactFragment

Comment: `if (cursor.moveToFirst()){ cursor.moveToNext();` <= here, move to first moves cursor to position 0 and moveto next to position 1(well ,if exits if not exits you have a problem) ... same with a phones cursor ...

Comment: are you sure? I read that the cursor actually starts before the data

Comment: I removed it and it still does not work correctly. So that can't be it

Comment: added the way I retrieve IDs. I can't see whats wrong though...

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a little late but hopefully it will help someone else with a similiar issue. Both of your cursor queries use the id as a string

```
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID+" = "+id,

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+" = "+contactId,
```

should be

```
ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = " + Uri.encode(id),

ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ Uri.encode(contactId),
```